# remove gray background inside form-input

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a code in bootstrap-vue 2.21.2:

```
<b-input-group class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
   <b-input-group-prepend is-text>
     <b-icon icon="search" variant="dark" />
   </b-input-group-prepend>
   <b-form-input
     id="filter-product"
     v-model="searchText"
     type="text"
     placeholder="Search Store"
    />
 </b-input-group>
```

reference for this code you can check to this link: [bootstrap icons](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/icons). As you can see, the output it should be like this:[image].
My question is how can I remove the gray background on the left hand side? I want it to appear without a gray background like this:[image]

I've done like this in my CSS but nothing change:

```
.input-group-prepend {
  background: transparent;
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: try changing the variant attribute

Comment: @GhostOps variant is for the color of the icon, it has no effect on the gray background

Comment: then how about using some css selectors? `b-icon[icon="search"] {background: #fff;}`

Comment: I've tried it with your css selector idea but it doesn't work @GhostOps

Comment: @GhostOps You can´t select `b-icon` like this because it renders and get´s another structure.

Comment: @Fabalance yeah, i realized it later after knowing that h uses bootstrap and vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a custom new class on `b-col` to wrap the `input-group` with the name for e.g `search-box`. HTML:

```
      <b-col
        cols="12"
        md="auto"
        class="search-box pr-md-2 pt-2 pt-md-0"
      >
        <b-input-group class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
          <b-input-group-prepend is-text>
            <b-icon icon="search" variant="dark" />
          </b-input-group-prepend>
          <b-form-input
            id="filter-product"
            v-model="searchText"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Cari Toko"
            @input="debounceInput"
          />
        </b-input-group>
      </b-col>
```

Then use the `deep selector` in vue to remove the gray background and remove the border. CSS:

```
.search-box >>> .input-group-prepend > .input-group-text {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-right: none !important;
}
.search-box >>> .input-group-prepend + input.form-control {
  border-left: none !important;
}
.search-box >>> .input-group-prepend + input.form-control:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first hurdle is to identify the tag that the component is rendered to. I also had problems scoping tagswith css, because their structure changed massively after rendering.

Your approach with `.input-group-prepend {background: transparent;}` was good, but targeted the wrong css property. As far as I see on the documentation, `.input-group-text` get´s the style `background-color: #e9ecef;`.

As `.input-group-text` is a child of `.input-group-prepend`, you should be able to change the background like:

```
.input-group-prepend .input-group-text {
  background-color: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS

```
.input-group-prepend .input-group-text {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.input-group-prepend input {
  border-left:0;
}
```